# How to force a PDF file to show horizontally in browser rather than vertically?

Tags: servlets, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm actually printing a generated PDF file in Java using the FileInputStream, HTTPServletResponse and OutputStream java objects. The content inside the file is printed correctly, the horizontal layout is fine, but the file is shown by the browser vertically.
Is there any header or parameter that I can use to force the browser to show it horizontally?

Just for your information, the document is generated starting from a Jasper iReport file, that already has the orientation set as "Landscape" inside the XML headers.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally** it's not possible (NOR advisable) to "enforce" any server desire on a clients browser. Thus such constructs as pop-up or print or switch toolbar off or attempt to protect PDF are usually FAILS as seen by the many Q&A here in Stack Overflow, or even classed by some browsers as viral.

One common feature of PDF viewers is that pages are scrolled in a vertical manner, and at most allow client to optionally show the pages as 2 cells wide by total pages/2.

HOWEVER that side by side function is not accessible to a server, even using "optional fragments" like #view or #zoom.

[image]

As an end point user, I can turn my tablet / monitor through 90 degrees and scroll all pages from Left to right, thus the very frivolous "off the cuff/shelf" answer is, only serve to mobile / hand held users.

You could write a "Modal" viewport in such a way that images are positioned in sideways fashion with a horizontal scroller, and that can be done just using CSS / JavaScript as seen in flipBook or other image viewer pages. but will not work with PDF viewers.